# How to add remote interpreter via ipv6 in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, ipv6, remote-debugging

My server has only an ipv6 address, and my computer can directly `ssh` to it via this address. But when I tried to add the remote interpreter on this server in Pycharm, it tells me `SFTP host is invalid` when it sees the ipv6 address.

How can I make it work? Thank you!

[image]

Update: adding brackets `[2001:da8:...]` helped pass the host syntax check. But now upon clicking "Ok", Pycharm tells me "java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable". How to pass this?

Comment: Have you checked that ssh and sftp works with the IPv6 address from the command line?

Comment: @PenguinBrian yes, `ssh -6 the_ipv6_address` works fine. But Pycharm says it is not a valid address, even won't let me click OK to try connecting to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I got that to work.

First, a valid IPV6 SFTP address must be wrapped in brackets. That is, instead of `2001:da8:201:1146:226:b9ff:....`, you should write `[2001:da8:201:1146:226:b9ff:....]`.

Second, if you do so you will find Pycharm telling you "java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable" and refuse to connect. This is an issue of Pycharm running under JDK 1.7 (yes, Pycharm is based on Java). To solve this:

1. Open **Help | Edit Custom VM Options**
2. Add **-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true** in it. You may also want to delete `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true` but I'm not sure whether it matters.
3. Restart Pycharm.

See here for more information:https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241215-Network-connectivity-issues-when-running-under-Java-1-7

Comment: I had to remove `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true`, with both keys it didn't work. After removal this solution worked for me too.

Comment: After changing these parameters, I found the SQLite database driver broken, saying something like `java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: ::1`

Comment: With PyCharm 2019.2 pro, the ipv4 option is named slightly differently: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true ; replacing that with -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true resolved the issue.

Comment: Note: Enabling the ipv6 option on PyCharm 2019.2 pro could result in side-effects such as PostgreSQL - postgres@localhost java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) if connecting to a Datasource via jdbc.  So it is better to retain and "comment out" the ipv4 option so that it can be reverted to as and when necessary .  Disabling or "commenting out" a vm option can be achieved by prefixing the option with a #.  pyCharm will need to be restarted every time a vm option is changed.

Answer (score 1):

If the error is coming from PyCharm (as opposed from ssh) I would suggest creating an alias in `~/.ssh/config`, for example:

```
Host myipv6host
HostName 2001:da8:201:1146:226:b9ff:....
```

That way you can tell pycharm to connect to myipv6host and it never has to see the ipv6 address.